# Interpretation of Born Rule In QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, probability, observables, born-rule

Can we born rule be used to find probability of a particle to exist in a region in QFT using the formula $\int_a^b \psi(x)\psi^*(x)dx$,where $\psi(x)$ is a fermionic field?
If yes, please provide citations.

I cannot understand how can born rule be applied to a particle since a field contains multiple particle and all particles are explained by the plane wave solutions of the field.

Comment: Can you be more specific why you think QFT might *not* be "compatible" with the Born rule? It's currently unclear what sort of answer one could give here except a simple "Yes, the Born rule applies to QFT".

Comment: @ACuriousMind Can we born rule be used to find probability of a particle to exist in a region in QFT using the formula $∫_b^aψ(x)ψ^*(x)dx$,where ψ(x) is a fermionic field? If yes, please provide citations.

I cannot understand how can born rule be applied to a particle since a field contains multiple particle and all particles are explained by the plane wave solutions of the field.

Answer (score 2):

The quantum fields are not wavefunctions, they are *operators*. The Born rule holds, but you need to apply it to the *states* of quantum field theory (mostly created by applying the field operators to the vacuum state), not to its operators.

Comment: You mean the notation needs to be $\int_a^b <x|\phi|p><p|\phi|x>dx$. Can you please provide some citations?

Comment: @Ace No, that's not what I mean (there are no position eigenstates in relativistic theories, for one). If you do not know the basics of quantum field theory necessary to understand my answer, I cannot really give you an answer here except that you should read a QFT textbook.